# Add Item in the Beginning of ListView Control

Tags: asp.net

I am using a ListView control and inside the ItemTemplate I generate a hyperlink:

```
<asp:ListView ID="categoryList"
    ItemType="products.Models.Category"
    runat="server"
    SelectMethod="GetCategories">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <a href="<%#: GetRouteUrl("ProductsByCategoryRoute", new {categoryName = Item.CategoryName}) %>">
                <%#: Item.CategoryName %>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemSeparatorTemplate></ItemSeparatorTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The GetCategories() function is defined as follows:

```
public IQueryable<Category> GetCategories()
{
    var _db = new products.Models.ProductContext();
    IQueryable<Category> query = _db.Categories;
    return query;
}
```

I want to insert a item dynamically called "All" at the first position when the ListView renders and want to give it a url of "/ProductList". How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

After you bind the list view you can say

```
Listview.items.insert(0,new listitem{value="something", text="something"});
```

Code not verified in ide

Comment: Thanks which event? Also how to generate the url?

Comment: I think is the event is databind, what do you need for the url. The url is not in the data you are binding?